# How to keep git fork up to date

Tags: github

I have tried

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19.git
```

and I get "not a git repository". I just want to keep the fork in sync with the root or whatever it's called. There's a new file added for each day and I want to not have to delete all of my files and refork. I somehow managed to do it once but for some reason I am now apparently committing to the original or something, I have no absolutely no clue what I'm doing.

Comment: Do you have any error messages, or output from the commits you've made that you can post? You need to add upstream as a remote, which is what you are doing, so there must be something else you're doing incorrectly.

Comment: "not a git resposity" is the message I get.

Comment: well, that's a big problem then. You are in a directory that isn't under version control. Git has no idea what to do with it. You first need to make a local clone from github. `git clone https://github.com/[your git account]/[your git repo].git`

Comment: Well, I don't think I have a git account, so let me get on that.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you are working from a clone of your fork:

```
git clone https://github.com/[your git account]/[your git repo].git
```

That will make a local copy of the fork that was made on github.

To keep your fork up to date with the upstream changes, you need to add upstream as a remote, which is what it appears you are trying to do (make sure you are in the directory for the local copy of the repo, or git will complain):

```
cd [local clone directory]
git remote add upstream https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19.git
```

Then fetch upstream:

```
git fetch upstream
```

Then check out your master branch, and merge the upstream version:

```
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
```

Note that `git checkout master` means the master *from your fork*, which we're assuming is missing some changes from the upstream source, which is then being merged in on the next line.

Comment: fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: You left out the key step. After git clone you need to cd into the work tree. I always forget that in real life too.  :)

Comment: @matt I'm assuming some passage of time between the clone and the rest, but you are right, that might not be obvious. updated.

Comment: So clone, then `cd COVID-19`. Now add the Johns Hopkins remote as upstream and fetch it. However you might also be able to update from Johns Hopkins right in your GitHub fork.

Comment: @matt that works too, with tha benefit that it won't require managing a remote and doing the merge locally, but the drawback of having to do the extra fiddling on github.